# Regex class not working on server side of GWT

Tags: java, regex, gwt

I've the following piece of code in the server folder of the module.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("/(B[A-Z0-9]{9})/");
Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(detailPageUrl);
```

But I still get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Line 14: The import java.util.regex cannot be resolved
[ERROR] Line 15: The import java.util.regex cannot be resolved
[ERROR] Line 202: Pattern cannot be resolved to a type
[ERROR] Line 202: Pattern cannot be resolved
[ERROR] Line 203: Matcher cannot be resolved to a type
```

I've imported

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

in the code.

I thought that Regex will work on the server side. Why is this not working?

Comment: Post your folder structure. Where on the "server" exactly is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Java environment first.  Like the Java version, classpath, etc.  The error clearly states that the package cannot be imported due to some reason.

Comment: Yup, I had included the server folder in the GWT module.xml file. That was causing GWT compiler to compile my server side code also.